# What happens if you use Skarner's ultimate and then Flash?

Tags: league-of-legends

Skarner's ultimate, Impale, allows him to basically grab an enemy and freely move around, dragging the enemy with him. But what happens if Skarner performs a Flash during this time?

Similarly, I'm assuming that using Ghost during this time would allow you to drag the enemy much further.

Obviously, this should be pretty easy to determine, but I don't have Skarner (nor am I interested in purchasing him at this time).

Comment: As the posters are answering, this must have been fixed when Blitzcrank was not allowed to do the same after rocket grabbin'

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Skarner can't flash while ulting someone; the ability icon greys out

Other moving effects, like ghost or an enemy push/pull *will* drag your victim along for the ride, though.

Comment: Nice way to counter a drag by grappling Skarner with Jax or Singed.

Comment: Wait... Jax grappling? Did you meant Blitzcrank? =)

Comment: @Lysarion, you're right, Jax jumps.

Comment: How about Skarner + Thresh's lantern?

Comment: I guess that would work since Aatrox passive + Thresh lantern works, there was a thread on reddit about Aatrox + Thresh. If Skarner + Thresh works then I would assume they will fix it.

Comment: Skarner's target will follow him around regardless of the method of movement - including through forced movement spells such as  Buster Shot and Dark Passage.

Comment: The thresh + skarner combo has indeed been patched

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use flash while using Skarner's ultimate. Ghost works as expected.