# What are the conditions and effects of grabbing a suppressed enemy?

Tags: pc, league-of-legends

Inspired by this question: [What happens if you use Skarner's ultimate and then Flash?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29330/what-happens-if-you-use-skarners-ultimate-and-then-flash) we can ask what does happen when an ally grabs a pulled-by-skarner enemy?

- Does it cancel Skarner's ultimate and get the champ, what about the damages?
- Does it fails ? (And do or don't consume the ability)
- Does it drag both players ? (unlikely)

This question can also be generalised to other suppress abilities.

Comment: You mean what happends when you Blitz-Pull an enemy who is being surpressed by a Skarner-Ult? I would say test it out in an custom game and there you'll find your answer. I must say pretty interesting Question xD

Comment: @MrME you can extend this to many things, what if Ashe stuns a pulled enemy, if Singed fling him. Or better, if Warwick ultimates on an enemy in Skarner ult :P (or the contrary too is interesting.)

Comment: Any reason you thought this deserved its own question instead of an extension within the previous question? (The answer is, by the way, the third option, as per [the previous question])(http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29330/what-happens-if-you-use-skarners-ultimate-and-then-flash/29331#29331)

Comment: @Raven the subject is different. The other question features action on Skarner who is acting. This one ask about action on the player that is forced into movement by Skarner acting. So instead the other question which where a counter of one team on Skarner, this question is axed on team play by one team with the same target.

Comment: @M'vy - Aha. I misread your question. I see what you're asking now. My apologies.

Comment: Different abilities that suppress the target also behave differently. Skarner's ult is unique in that it grants you the ability to forcefully move the target. So what you seem to be asking is "How do abilities affect champions that are suppressed?" The answer is going to have to take into account the Ultimates from Malzahar, Warwick and Skarner, and any others I may be forgetting, as there may be different interactions with each.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppression does not prevent move-block abilities from having their normal effect.

Malzahar's ultimate has a leash range, it is possible to cancel a friendly Malzahar's ultimate by pulling the target out of leash range. If your move block does not place the victim outside of leash range, Malzahar's ultimate will complete as normal.

Warwick's ultimate does *not* have a leash range (but see below). If you move his victim, he will continue to channel and deal damage while appearing to savage thin air.

This youtube shows a Blitz grab connecting shortly after Skarner's ultimate begins:

Skarner's ultimate will not be broken by move-block abilities - instead, it will override the move black shortly after it begins with its own effect.

ETA: Xypherous [recently announced](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=31242645#31242645) planned changes to Malzahar & Warwick's ultimates:

> We're doing a change (or a bugfix, depending on your point of view) on
>   both Warwick and Malzahar. Their ultimates will be treated like
>   leashes... because they kind of are. (You can't QSS leashes. You can
>   only break them via distance.)
>
> What this means is that QSS will break the stunning effect on you but
>   until you get out of range of them, it won't cancel the damage and
>   other effects these characters will be doing. Malzahar will get his
>   full Nether Grasp until they break the leash and Warwick typically
>   gets 2 (maybe 3) more swipes before the target walks away.